# 'This webpage is not available' for a brief moment - Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Something weird starting to happen today in Chrome.

I randomly get the "This webpage is not available" message when visiting a site, but only for a brief moment, like 1 second, then the page displays.

Why is this happening? And how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it just started recently, and it briefly shows an about:blank or similar, it seems to be because of a Chrome update. I noticed it in Canary a few weeks back, now in stable. If you use slow net, like tethering through a cell, you will see it does this badly. There is no "loading" indicator, it just sits there like nothing happened...10-30seconds later it  puts the url back in and starts rendering the page. Previously it would start loading the page...no blankpage then url thing like its doing now.

I think it has something to do with Chrome pre-fetch, so perhaps turning off predictive settings may help resolve it by attempting to run less async scripts. Besides that, it looks like an "oops" on their part. Im sure it will be repaired in some coming update.